# How to perform pl-c keystroke?

Tags: emacs, plantuml

I'm using `platuml-mode` on *GNU Emacs 25.0.50.1 (x86_64-w64-mingw32)*. After executing <kbd>M-x</kbd> `plantuml-complete-symbol` <kbd>RET</kbd> it displays a hint in the minibuffer:

```
You can run the command `plantuml-complete-symbol' with M-x pl-c RET
```

What does the <kbd>pl-c</kbd> keystrokes mean? How to perform it in order to get the `plantuml-complete-symbol` command run instead of invoking it from the minibuffer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that after <kbd>M-x</kbd> you can just type `pl-c` (rather than the complete `plantuml-complete-symbol`) and then <kbd>RET</kbd> in order to run that command.

BTW, I recommend you file a feature request to the authors of plantuml-mode asking them to implement a `completion-at-point-function` so you don't need a separate `plantuml-complete-symbol` command but can just use the generic `completion-at-point` (which is bound to `M-TAB` by default but can also be triggered by `TAB` if you set `tab-always-indent` to `complete`).